# "2 is the only even prime number" using quantifiers

Tags: logic, prime-numbers, quantifiers

if "2 is the only even prime number"

- Prove using quantifiers
  Let P(x) = x is prime number 
  ∃xP(x)

AND

- Negate the statement that you have
  ¬∃xP(x)= ∀x(¬P(x))

Is this right?

edited: 
what about this? 
∀n ∈ N(n is even ∧ n is prime ⇒ n=2)

Comment: Why do you think that $∃xP(x)$ translates "2 is the only even prime number" ?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA  because there is an existence of one number that is the only even prime number which is 2.

Comment: IMO $∃xP(x)$  translates "there is a red bag on my desk".....

Comment: If $P(x)$ symbolize "$x$ is a Prime number", then $∃x P(x)$ translates "there is a Prime number".

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA owhhh okay thanks...

Comment: This is a duplicate question, as Daphne knows.

Comment: From yesterday: [Duplicate question: Predicate logic English translation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2743875/predicate-logic-english-sentence-translation#comment5661493_2743875)

Answer (score 3):

Hint: The statement "2 is the only even prime" becomes, in slightly more formula-friendly language

> There does not exist a number which all of the following are true:
>
> - It is even
> - It is different from 2
> - It is prime

Comment: I'm sorry but can you explain it clearer?

Comment: @DaphneChan: What exactly is unclear to you in Arthur's answer?

Comment: @celtschk I'll try to explain what i know
which is, 2 is an even number that is prime, so there is no other number that is even and prime?

Comment: @DaphneChan: Imagine you'd know nothing about the meaning of "prime", that it would be a word you'd never heard, like "brillig". Now if someone told you that $2$ is an even number that is brillig, would you be able to conclude that there's no other even brillig number?